# How to fix PC which stopped working after accidentally disconnecting one or more leads inside?

Tags: boot

I've broken the problem description into 3 phases, as the state of the PC's error reporting has moved through 3 phases:

I opened the PC up to try to find the make of the power supply and in doing so I accidentally disconnected one or more leads. I reconnected the only one I could see how to reconnect, which was a fan.

**Phase 1**

When I next tried to boot it up, a blue screen came up with a message along the lines of 'Your PC ran into a problem' with a few options. I selected boot up in Safe Mode (Windows 8.1 by the way) and it booted up, but no access to The Internet, so I rebooted, which was in normal mode by default and it worked. The same thing happened a couple of times over the next few days, but the safe mode then normal mode trick worked... until when playing a game one night the PC just shut down.

**Phase 2**

Next time I booted up, a black screen with the message 'Preparing Automatic Repair'

Then 'Diagnosing your PC'

Then 'Repairing Disk Errors. This might take an hour.'

Then some spinning balls showing the PC's doing something, but 90 mins later and nothing changed.

**Phase 3**

Now when I boot up, I'm faced with a black screen and the message 'Preparing Automatic Repair', then 'Diagnosing PC' and then some spinning balls showing the PC's doing something, but 90 mins later and nothing's changed. Yes, this is the same as Phase 2 minus the message 'Repairing Disk Errors. This might take an hour.'

**More information**

The reason I initially opened the PC up to try to find out the make of the power supply was because I'd been asked to do so by someone responding to a question I asked on a forum about why the PC seemed to be giving off a funny smell when playing certain games.

**The Question**

However, given that the PC was functioning fine until the accidental disconnection of 1 or more leads (there are 2 leads presently disconnected: one is power LED, but I had this connected at one point and it didn't fix the problem. The other lead is a smallish 4 hole black lead: maybe it should be connected to something but I can't see where it could go at the moment), I'm wondering if the problem could be solved simply by something being reconnected or connected differently. I might take the PC to someone my father knows who works with PCs, but in the meantime, I'd thought I'd just ask here to see if anyone can help.

**Pictures of leads**

Here's a link (which I hope you'll be able to view) to 8 pictures of the leads in question (here are only 3 leads in question). 1 is the white fan lead which I reconnected. 1 is the power LED. Connecting this didn't solve the problem. The other 1 is the 4 hole black lead which the linked picture is of. Links to the other 7 pictures (6 of which are of the leads) should hopefully be available from the page linked. One of them is a random picture of a game. I don't know how that got in there. Please ignore it.

[Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4REm.jpg)

Comment: Could you take a picture of the leads in question?

Comment: I've done that now: please see the question for a link to the pictures, which I hope you'll be able to view.

Comment: You did connect the (case) fan again, right? Where does the black lead come from?

Comment: It seems that your hard drive may have gotten corrupted in the crash. Try enabling SMART monitoring in the bios (typically in the advanced section) and see if it returns any errors.

Comment: @T.C. I connected the fan again, yes. The black lead comes form a black connector which connects to a white connector. The black connector also has leads coming from the DVD/CD and the white connector has a bunch of leads which run to two other white connectors which then have leads going into what I think must be the graphics card.

Comment: @slow_excellence Thanks. I've just enabled SMART monitoring. Now what do I do: save changes and exit? Doing that just seems to result in the same error messages.

Comment: Your hard drive is most likely dead/corrupted. Sorry for any confusion on the SMART part, I'm still waking up and completely forgot that you actually need to be able to log into windows in order to read the information.

Comment: You can use any hard drive no matter what other components are in the PC. It would be a good idea to have a professional look at the computer (in case of failure, they can also help you recover some of your data) before you purchase a new hard drive.

Comment: @slow_excellence Ok. Thanks a lot. Sorry I just deleted my previous comment because it was saying move the discussion to chat. In retrospect, it would've probably been better to leave the comment and move the discussion to chat, but for some reason I'm getting an error when i try to move the discussion to chat. Do you have any idea what might have killed the hard drive, if that is indeed what happened?

Comment: I'd love to except that I am unable to use the chat. The version of IE my work uses forces the page into a refresh loop and I have to close the tab.

Comment: Ok, no problems.

Comment: @slow_excellence It was indeed the hard drive: see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the hard drive indeed failed, so I had it replaced and the PC works again. After having it fixed though, the PC shutdown again while I was using it and I thought 'Oh no! Not again.' Thankfully though, it was the power strip: switching to a different one I found that the PC was still ok.